# How to use pandas apply method, in case you need a parameterized function

Tags: python, pandas, replace, parameters, apply

**Input:**

```
0      1     2
TNN    R11W  MSLQEMFRFPRGLLLGSVLLVASAPATL
ASTN1  E5V   MALAALCALLACCWGPAAVLATAAGDVDPSK
HSPB7  H19P  MSHRTSSTFRAERSFHSSHSSSSSSTSSSASRALPAQDPPMEK
CLCNKB C3Y   MECFVGLREGSSGNPVTLQELWGPCPRIRRGIRG
SZRD1  P10L  MEDEEVAESWEEAADSGEIDRRLEKKL
```

**Expected output:**

```
0      1     2
TNN    R11W  MSLQEMFRFPWGLLLGSVLLVASAPATL
ASTN1  E5V   NaN
HSPB7  H19P  MSHRTSSTFRAERSFHSSPSSSSSSTSSSASRALPAQDPPMEK
CLCNKB C3Y   MEYFVGLREGSSGNPVTLQELWGPCPRIRRGIRG
SZRD1  P10L  NaN
```

**Code: examples**

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

with open(file1, 'r') as mvf:
    lines_1 = [line.rstrip('\n').split(',') for line in mvf]

df = pd.DataFrame(lines_1)

class CharacterReplacer:
    def __init__(self,varcolname=df[1], textcolname=df[2]):
        self.varcolname=varcolname
        self.textcolname=textcolname

    def text_replacer_informed_from_variant_column(self,row):
        variant_desc=row[self.varcolname]
        c, p, r =  (variant_desc[0], int(variant_desc[1:-1]), variant_desc[-1])
        row[self.textcolname]=CharacterReplacer.replace_a_char_in_a_pos(row[self.textcolname], c, p, r)
        return row

    @staticmethod
    def replace_a_char_in_a_pos(target_seq, pos, fromchar, tochar):
        pos=pos-1
        if( target_seq[pos]!=fromchar ):
            sys.stderr.write("{} does not match with {}".format(target_seq[pos],fromchar))

        out_seq= target_seq[:pos]+  tochar + target_seq[pos+1:]
        return out_seq

charreplacer=CharacterReplacer(df[1],df[2])
df_new = df.apply(charreplacer.text_replacer_informed_from_variant_column, axis=1)
```

I wanna change a character in 'column 2' with the index of 'column 1'. For example, in first row, if I check the index of 'column 1', I will fine 'R' in 11th character of 'column 2'. If the character is 'R', I wanna change it as 'W'. If not, I wanna write 'NaN' in the cell. How can I replace a character of 'column2' with the information of 'column1'.

Comment: @MayankPorwal. Please reopen the question. Finally, the problem is not the same. The OP reused my code from the previous question in this answer and now the problem is different.

Comment: @Corralien Got it. THanks.

Comment: @LoganLee. Why don't you read your file with `pd.read_csv`? `df = pd.read_csv('file1', header=None)` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your code.

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

# Try: df = pd.read_csv('file1', header=None)
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['TNN', 'ASTN1', 'HSPB7', 'CLCNKB', 'SZRD1'],
                   1: ['R11W', 'E5V', 'H19P', 'C3Y', 'P10L'],
                   2: ['MSLQEMFRFPRGLLLGSVLLVASAPATL',
                       'MALAALCALLACCWGPAAVLATAAGDVDPSK',
                       'MSHRTSSTFRAERSFHSSHSSSSSSTSSSASRALPAQDPPMEK',
                       'MECFVGLREGSSGNPVTLQELWGPCPRIRRGIRG',
                       'MEDEEVAESWEEAADSGEIDRRLEKKL']})
```

Code:

```
class CharacterReplacer:
    def __init__(self, varcolname, textcolname):
        self.varcolname = varcolname
        self.textcolname = textcolname

    def text_replacer_informed_from_variant_column(self, row):
        variant_desc = row[self.varcolname]
        c, p, r =  (variant_desc[0], int(variant_desc[1:-1]), variant_desc[-1])
        row[self.textcolname] = CharacterReplacer.replace_a_char_in_a_pos(row[self.textcolname], p, c, r)
        return row

    @staticmethod
    def replace_a_char_in_a_pos(target_seq, pos, fromchar, tochar):
        pos -= 1
        if(target_seq[pos] != fromchar):
            sys.stderr.write(f"{target_seq[pos]} does not match with {fromchar}")
            return np.NaN

        out_seq = f"{target_seq[:pos]}{tochar}{target_seq[pos+1:]}"
        return out_seq
```

Use:

```
charreplacer = CharacterReplacer(1, 2)  # 1 and 2 are the column names
out = df.apply(charreplacer.text_replacer_informed_from_variant_column, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
        0     1                                            2
0     TNN  R11W                 MSLQEMFRFPWGLLLGSVLLVASAPATL
1   ASTN1   E5V                                          NaN
2   HSPB7  H19P  MSHRTSSTFRAERSFHSSPSSSSSSTSSSASRALPAQDPPMEK
3  CLCNKB   C3Y           MEYFVGLREGSSGNPVTLQELWGPCPRIRRGIRG
4   SZRD1  P10L                                          NaN
```

**Edit**

Is your data file look like:

```
TNN,R11W,MSLQEMFRFPRGLLLGSVLLVASAPATL
ASTN1,E5V,MALAALCALLACCWGPAAVLATAAGDVDPSK
HSPB7,H19P,MSHRTSSTFRAERSFHSSHSSSSSSTSSSASRALPAQDPPMEK
CLCNKB,C3Y,MECFVGLREGSSGNPVTLQELWGPCPRIRRGIRG
SZRD1,P10L,MEDEEVAESWEEAADSGEIDRRLEKKL
```

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you check the format of your input file, please?

Comment: Absolutely right!

Comment: So use: `df = pd.read_csv('file1', header=None)`

Comment: Awesome!! You're the best Corralien! Thank you for everything!!